# Zk spreadsheet zssjsp jar

Tags: jsp, spreadsheet, zk, zul

Hi I'm new to **zk spreadsheet**. I'm following [this](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Spreadsheet_Quick_Start_Guide/Integrate_ZK_Spreadsheet_with_JSP_Application) tutorial for starting with **zk spreadsheet** with **jsp**.

In the tutorial it has been mentioned to use **zssjsp jar** but I cannot find the jar In the download links provided. It's basically used for tags in Jsp. I want to use "Windows" tag in Jsp. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the link you provided and clicked on the [download link](http://www.zkoss.org/download/zkspreadsheet) and then downloaded the first file in the list (`zssee-bin-eval-3.9.1.zip` at the moment). In it, the `zssjsp.jar` is at

```
zssee-bin-eval-3.9.1.zip\zssee-bin-eval-3.9.1\dist\lib
```